# Ruby, delete null values of a string

Tags: ruby, string, null

**Example:**

```
String test="hi\000\000\000"
```

**Problem:**
Some methods require a string to be without nulls, how can I delete all null values of a string?

```
.split("\000",1) gives me an error: 'force_encoding' method doesn't exist
.gsub('\000','') does nothing
```

Comment: `'\000'` in Ruby evaluates to `"\\000"`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even more simple:

```
test.delete("\000")
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using double quotes, so `test.gsub("\000", '')`.

Comment: Forgot that ' ' doesn't parse escape characters, thanks. (5 minutes till I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Right now I tried this in JRuby and it worked:

```
test.gsub(/\000/, '')
```

Note that I am using a regex in the gsub and not a string.

Comment: Works as well (though my natural enemy is Regex)

Comment: `Regexp` literal replacements are ever-so-slightly faster than single-character-string replacements in MRI. Not sure about JRuby.

Comment: @Bob Aman: Indeed. Do you know why? Anyway, I think a regexp is overkill for this case.

Comment: Not really. My guess would be that the Regexp code goes through a better optimized code-path.